# Cannot find node robot_pose_ekf?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed robot_pose_ekf according to http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf, but when I run the launch file, thisi is the errer I receive

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_pose_ekf/base_footprint_frame: base_footprint
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq: 30.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame: odom_combined
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout: 1.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used: True
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21

NODES
  /
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [64634]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 7023c802-54c3-11e7-8be4-14feb5de14ae
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [64647]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf]: can't locate node [robot_pose_ekf] in package [robot_pose_ekf]
```

How do I debug thsi error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264109/cannot-find-node-robot_pose_ekf-?/) by [Anurag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28030/anurag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into the same problem because I had downloaded the source codes into my catkin workspace and compiled it. Deleting all the associated files and folders from the build/ and devel/ directories in my workspace and running catkin_make clean solved it for me.

---

Originally posted by [emilyfy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33444/emilyfy/) with karma: 26 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0